# Problemas al definir rutas en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

necesito ayuda en al definir unas rutas en laravel, la cuestion es que no se como definir de la manera correcta las rutas de las siguientes funciones que estan dentro de un contralador.

```
class ContactoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $miscontactos=DB::table('contactos')->limit(5)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return view('contacto.contacto',compact('miscontactos'));
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('contacto.nuevo');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'nombre'=>'required|string','apellidos'=>'required|string',
            'fecha_nacimiento'=>'required|string','sexo'=>'required|string',
            'direccion'=>'required|string|min:5|max:200'
        ]);
        DB::table('contactos')->insert([
            'nombre'=>$request->nombre,'apellidos'=>$request->apellidos,
            'fecha_nacimiento'=>$request->fecha_nacimiento,'sexo'=>$request->sexo,
            'direccion'=>$request->direccion,
            'create_at'=>now(), 'update_at'=>now()
        ]);
        return back()->with('estado','El contacto se guardo con exito');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    /*public function show($id)*/


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $contacto=DB::table('contactos')->where('id',$id)->first();
        return view('contacto.actualizar', compact('contacto'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'nombre'=>'required|string','apellidos'=>'required|string',
            'fecha_nacimiento'=>'required|string','sexo'=>'required|string',
            'direccion'=>'required|string|min:5|max:200'
        ]);
        $contacto=DB::table('contactos')->where('id',$id)->update($request->only('nombre','apellidos','fecha_nacimiento','direccion','update_at'));
        return back()->with('estado','El contacto se edito con exito');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $contacto=DB::table('contactos')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return back()->with('estado','El contacto ha sido elimidado con exito');
    }
}
```

Estas son mis vistas:

```
@extends('contacto.base')
@section('contenidos')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form action="{{route('contacto.update',$contacto->id)}}" method="POST">
            <h2>Actualizar</h2>

            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Nombre</legend>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" value="{{old('name')?? $contacto->nombre}} ">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('nombre')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Apellidos</legend>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" value="{{old('apellidos') ?? $contacto->apellidos}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('apellidos')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Fecha de Nacimiento</legend>
                <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" min="1910-01-01" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" value="{{old('fecha_nacimiento') ?? $contacto->fecha_nacimiento}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('fecha_nacimiento')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Sexo</legend>
                @if($contacto->sexo == 'Femenino')
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino" checked="true">Femenino
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino">Masculino
                </label>
                @else
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino">Femenino
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino" checked="true">Masculino
                </label>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Direccion</legend>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Direccion" value="{{old('direccion') ?? $contacto->direccion}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('direccion')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            @if(session()->has('estado'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('estado')}}</div>
            @endif
        </form>
        @csrf
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Vista 2:

```
@extends('contacto.base')
@section('contenidos')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form action="{{route('contacto.update',$contacto->id)}}" method="POST">
            <h2>Actualizar</h2>

            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Nombre</legend>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" value="{{old('name')?? $contacto->nombre}} ">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('nombre')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Apellidos</legend>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" value="{{old('apellidos') ?? $contacto->apellidos}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('apellidos')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Fecha de Nacimiento</legend>
                <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" min="1910-01-01" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" value="{{old('fecha_nacimiento') ?? $contacto->fecha_nacimiento}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('fecha_nacimiento')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Sexo</legend>
                @if($contacto->sexo == 'Femenino')
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino" checked="true">Femenino
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino">Masculino
                </label>
                @else
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino">Femenino
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino" checked="true">Masculino
                </label>
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Direccion</legend>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Direccion" value="{{old('direccion') ?? $contacto->direccion}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('direccion')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            @if(session()->has('estado'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('estado')}}</div>
            @endif
        </form>
        @csrf
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Vista 3:

```
@extends('contacto.base')
@section('contenidos')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form action="{{route('contacto.store')}}" method="POST">
            <h2>Crear Nuevo Contacto</h2>

            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Nombre</legend>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" value="{{old('name')}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('nombre')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Apellidos</legend>
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" value="{{old('apellidos')}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('apellidos')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Fecha de Nacimiento</legend>
                <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" min="1910-01-01" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento" value="{{old('fecha_nacimiento')}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('fecha_nacimiento')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Sexo</legend>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Femenino">Femenino
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="Masculino">Masculino
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <legend>Direccion</legend>
                <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" placeholder="Direccion" value="{{old('direccion')}}">
                <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('direccion')}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            @if(session()->has('estado'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{session('estado')}}</div>
            @endif
        </form>
        @csrf
        {{method_field('PUT')}}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Estaba haciendo las rutas asi pero creo que estan mal:

```
Route::get('/',[ContactoController::class,'index'])->name('base');
Route::get('/1',[ContactoController::class,'create'])->name('contacto.nuevo');
Route::get('/2',[ContactoController::class,'store'])->name('contacto.nuevo');
Route::get('/3',[ContactoController::class,'edit'])->name('contacto.actualizar');
Route::get('/4',[ContactoController::class, 'update'])->name('contacto.actualizar');
Route::get('/4',[ContactoController::class,'destroy'])->name('eliminar');
```

Me sale siempre este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ahí no avanzo en la definicion de rutas, eh leido algunos articulos pero no logro entender bien. Quiero que los datos almacenados en la base de datos se pueda mostrar en las vistas usando las funciones pero al momento de la definicion de rutas no me sale el error de definicion.

Comment: Tienes tu ruta con el name -> contacto.actualizar y el error te dice que contacto.edit, otra cosa, las rutas en Laravel post es para el método store que es para guardar los datos, put es para actualizar, si todas las rutas son get no funcionara el crud

Answer (score 0):

Tú estás tratando de ir a la ruta dominio.com/contacto/store

```
<form action="{{ route('contacto.store') }}" method="POST">
```

Esa ruta no la tienes definida, tú al método store le estás dando el alias NUEVO

```
Route::get('/2',[ContactoController::class,'store'])->name('contacto.nuevo');
```

por tanto en el formulario deberás llamarlo como:

```
<form action="{{ route('contacto.nuevo') }}" method="POST">
```

De todas maneras te encontrarás con el error 404 al no tener el token en los formularios.
Tendrás que editar tu formulario de la siguiente manera.

```
<form action="{{route('contacto.store')}}" method="POST">
@csrf
```

lee lo que hace [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf)

Answer (score -1):

La forma para crear una ruta en Laravel es la siguiente

```
Route::get('perfil', [userController::class, 'index'])->name('perfil')->middleware('auth');
```

Donde el primer parametro es el nombre de la ruta que aparecera en la barra de navegacion. Por ejemplo **MiPagina.com/perfil**
El segundo parametro es el controlador junto con el metodo a ejecutar.

El metodo name se utiliza para darle un nombre a la ruta y poder llamarla por ejemplo:

```
 // esto llamara al controlador de la ruta creada anteriormente llamada perfil
 <form action="{{route('perfil')}}" method="GET">
```

Las vistas se retornan de esta manera en el controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('verperfil');
}
```

Donde Ingreso es el nombre de la vista que esta en la carpeta vistas, si por ejemplo la vista que necesitas esta en una carpeta la llamarias de esta manera:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('carpeta.verperfil');
}
```